# How to Create Flowchart from java source code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sequence-diagram

I would like to create the flowchart or sequence diagram from my java source code.
Is there any plug-in which can help me do that?

Comment: Are you trying to represent your source flow as sequence diagrams(check StarUML) or actually building a tool which will create sequence diagram using some data?

Comment: I have my full project source code in Eclipse. I just want to understand the flowchart of the whole project. something like call hierarchy or sequence diagram.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse plugin or a Open source tool to reverse engineer java code for sequence diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972706/eclipse-plugin-or-a-open-source-tool-to-reverse-engineer-java-code-for-sequence-d)

Comment: This question is FINE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this post meant for flow chart?
Do You mean Sequence Diagram or Class Diagram
eUML is a good tool to create Class Diagram or Sequence Diagram
You can find it at http://www.soyatec.com/main.php

Answer (score 8):

[ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/) is a free UML tool which can creates sequence diagrams. Another commercial tool to create sequence diagrams from existing code is [Architexa](http://www.architexa.com/). I use Architexa very often at my daily work.

Comment: Just fyi, Architexa has also just recently released a free edition.

Answer (score 4):

Our tool, [Code Rocket for Eclipse](http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/Products/CodeRocketForEclipse) can produce both pseudocode and flowcharts from Java (and C/C++ code). The design views can be edited and any changes forward engineered into the code. It is not a free tool,  but there is a free 30-day trial. Also it is only for Eclipse 32-bit.

Comment: Just a quick update, Code Rocket for Eclipse now supports 64-bit versions of Eclipse.

Comment: update, it is an exe file and supports only windows

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a plugin for this but there are certainly techniques for doing this. If there is no plugin available, theoretically, one could follow the approach of such techniques to build one. One such technique that comes to mind is contained in the paper [Object naming analysis for reverse-engineered sequence diagrams](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1062510) by Atanas Rountev and Beth Harkness Connell.

Here's the abstract:

> UML sequence diagrams are commonly used to represent object interactions in software systems. This work considers the problem of extracting UML sequence diagrams from existing code for the purposes of software understanding and testing. A static analysis for such reverse engineering needs to map the interacting objects from the code to sequence diagram objects. We propose an interprocedural dataflow analysis algorithm that determines precisely which objects are the receivers of certain messages, and assigns the appropriate diagram objects to represent them. Our experiments indicate that the majority of message receivers can be determined exactly, resulting in highly-precise object naming for reverse-engineered sequence diagrams.

Comment: Probably two far removed from a useful implementation, but nonetheless an interesting reference!

Answer (score 0):

I found this Eclipse plugin **Flowchart4j V 2.0.0** et
[http://www.codeswat.com/](http://www.codeswat.com/cswat/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=34&Itemid=55)
You can use it for ***flowchart*** or ***sequence diagram*** and export it to ***MS Visio***.
It has only one disadvantage. You have to pay for it.

Comment: I wrote it. But works great :-)