# How to generate flowcharts in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for a flowchart plugin for eclipse (I am using eclipse for Android) and stumbled upon `CodeRocket for Eclipse`.

- Is it the best flow chart generator eclipse?

I tried `Code Rocket for Eclipse`.

Did it exactly as described [here](http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/updates/CodeRocketForEclipse/) but I am  getting this error

`Could not create the view: Plug-in com.rapidqualitysystems.coderocket.ui was unable to load class com.rapidqualitysystems.coderocket.views.EclipseFlowchartEditor.`

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Added StackTrace**
The full stacktrace will clutter the screen and is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?j8zlriadxgd2yny) and starting five line are below

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/rapidqualitysystems/coderocket/views/EclipseFlowchartEditor : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
```

**Edit 2** First error was that `Code Rocket for Eclipse` worked with Java 7 only. I upgraded my Java to 7, later Support for the `CodeRocket for Eclipse` informed that the software only works with 32-bit version of eclipse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374159/how-to-create-flowchart-from-java-source-code-in-eclipse

Comment: Just to let you know that Code Rocket for Eclipse now supports 64-bit versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause of your problem ist that

- The plugin containing the class com.rapidqualitysystems.coderocket.views.EclipseFlowchartEditor is missing
- Or the class EclipseFlowchartEditor itself requires another class that is missing

Sometimes its very tricky to track down such kinds of problems.

- Check whether you get a more detailed error message or a stack trace when you push the "Details" button.
- Check also if there is a error message in the Error Log view.
- Try to find the plugin that should provide the class EclipseFlowchartEditor and show whether the Plugins view lists this plugin.

Comment: I have added the detailed Stacktrace.

Comment: The UnsupportedClassVersionError indicates that your byte code has been compiled with a newer version of Java than the one you are currently using to run the code. Modify your plugin's Manifest such that it uses a newer Java version for compilation and it should work (hopefully).

Comment: I could **not** understand your suggestion can you describe it in little more detail? You may edit your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got you wrong. You are just using the Flow chart editor for Android development right? I think, the problem is that you are running your Eclipse distribution with an older Java version (probably Java 5 or 6?). But the plugin you installed has been built with Java 7 (im not sure, but I think, Java minor version 51 is a Java 7 according to other online posts). If you run your Eclipse with a Java 7 SDK, everything should work fine.

Comment: Yes, Java version 51 leads to Java 7 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)

Comment: Ok, I checked my computer has Java Version 6 Update 31. I am upgrading it to Java version 7 update 4. Wonder why Java did not asked in for update? Get back to you.